# Dell XPS 630i will not boot into bios and sounds beeps

Tags: boot, bios, dell-xps, beep-code

I have a Dell XPS 603i which was my fathers.  One day it just died and I have been trying to figure out why.

A few things I have done/found is:

- both hard drives when connected to another computer are RAW.  I know this isn’t good and the data seems unrecoverable in anything I’ve tried to date.  That’s another matter for another question however.  I was hoping that I could get a new hard drive, install Windows 10 and use it to essentially use the computer again without erasing the RAW data on the existing hard drives.  I unplugged both drives hoping I could at least make it to the bios, which failed.
- one fan was broken on the graphics card.  This was on the secondary card (dual card support) so we removed that and still have the primary card connected.
- All lights and fans start when I plug it in.
- I removed the CMOS battery for 30 seconds hoping to reset the bios and then put in a new battery.

I have linked to a YouTube video of me powering up the computer and the associated beeps.  https://youtu.be/c0rhKyOxTBY

I am at a loss as my experience with computer internals is fairly  limited.  What would be causing the beeps and is there any way I can fix it or other things I can check and test?

Comment: Might also be a RAM issue. Try to remove or swap some of the RAM modules (must be done pair by pair). Or simply check if they (still) properly in place.

Comment: So, I’m going to have to buy some ram (2 modules?) to try this, I assume. I did take them out and reseat them.  When I did this there were two green and two blue RAM modules (different sizes).  I think I know what you mean pair by pair

Comment: Yes, it seems that your RAM needs to be installed in pairs. Before wasting your money for bying new ones: Since having 2 pairs of RAM, try to boot with only one of the pairs (green or blue ones) to find out if one of them led to your problem.